# AHK RegExMatch: extract tags from string

Tags: autohotkey

From a string for example "#tag1 keyword1 #tag2 keyword2"
I want to extract tag1 and tag2
I have tried:

```
sPat := "O)#([^#\s]*)"  ; return Object array

If RegExMatch(sSearch,sPat,oTag) {
    MsgBox % oTag.Count
    Loop % oTag.Count(){
        tag := oTag[A_Index]
        MsgBox % tag
    }
}
```

But it only finds the first tag. (oTag.Count=1; tag="tag1")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the final solution I came to:

```
sPat := "#([^#\s]*)" 
sSpace :="%20"
Pos=1
While Pos :=    RegExMatch(sSearch, sPat, tag,Pos+StrLen(tag)) 
    sTags := sTags . sSpace . tag1
```

(I found it in some AHK forum but didn't write down the reference. )

Answer (score 0):

RegExMatch only finds one match. The "O" mode returns sub-patterns in the one match.  For example, you could extract both the tag and the keyword at the same time with:

**This finds a regex pattern within a string and parses out two subpatterns from the match**

```
sSearch := "#tag1a keyword1 #tag2 keyword2" 
sPat := "O)#(\S+)\s+(\S+)"

if (RegExMatch(string, regex, fields))
  MsgBox % fields[1] "=" fields[2]
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

What you want is something like this:

**This finds all matching occurrences of a regex pattern within a string**

```
string := "#tag1 keyword1 #tag2 keyword2" 
regex  := "O)#(\S+)\s+(\S+)"
pos := 1

while (pos && RegExMatch(string, regex, fields, pos)) {
  MsgBox % fields[1] "=" fields[2]
  pos := fields.Pos[2] + 1
}
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough: the search string can have randomly ordered tags and keywords. See my solution posted as answer.